# how to read and write the properties file which is in my Java Resources / src / configuration.properties in java

Tags: java

I don't know how to read the properties file which is in  Java Resources / src / configuration.properties file. I want to write on that properties file also.

Thanks.

Comment: What you tried ? Are you getting any exception?Are u using maven?

Comment: "I have tried nothing and I'm all out of ideas"

Comment: start to write it. and if you have problems - you can ask

Comment: a simple search would have solved your problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what you tried, and from where you tried to read the properties file.

If you want to read properties files from java use this code :

```
public class ReadPropertiesFile {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            File file = new File("test.properties");//give the properties file path
            FileInputStream fileInput = new FileInputStream(file);
            Properties properties = new Properties();
            properties.load(fileInput);
            fileInput.close();

            Enumeration enuKeys = properties.keys();
            while (enuKeys.hasMoreElements()) {
                String key = (String) enuKeys.nextElement();
                String value = properties.getProperty(key);
                System.out.println(key + ": " + value);
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```